# Cannot add Invoice in QBXML request due to the Customer FullName

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

When sending a `CustomerQueryRq` in qbxml, it returns:

```
    500: The query request has not been fully completed. 
There was a required element ("Client Name") that could not be found in QuickBooks.
```

So then I send a `CustomerAddRq` that returns:

```
3100: The name "Client Name" of the list element is already in use.
```

And the `InvoiceAddRq` fails saying:

```
            3140: There is an invalid reference to QuickBooks Customer "Client Name" 
    in the Invoice.  QuickBooks error message: The specified name is either 
invalid or of the wrong type.
```

How could the Customer with FullName "Client Name" already be in use, but then it is not found when trying to add an Invoice for that Customer?

Am I misinterpreting these error messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your answer right here:

- The specified name is **either invalid or of the wrong type.**

This tells me that there is NOT a customer with that exact name, but that there's a VENDOR or an EMPLOYEE or a OTHER NAME entry with the same name.

The `Name` field in QuickBooks is a `UNIQUE` key across Vendors, Employees, Other Name entries, and Customers.

Comment: Thank you, yes it turned out to be a Vender having the same name

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** Always escape and trim your data and check the length before it is passed to QB. Always refer to [OSR](https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html).

1. First of all try to find a customer by name using `CustomerQueryRq` xml:

   ```
   // CustomerQuery Request
   $name = 'John Doe';

   $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <?qbxml version="13.0"?>
   <QBXML>
       <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
           <CustomerQueryRq>
               <NameFilter>
                   <MatchCriterion>StartsWith</MatchCriterion>
                   <Name>' . $name . '</Name>
               </NameFilter>
           </CustomerQueryRq>
       </QBXMLMsgsRq>
   </QBXML>';
   ```
2. Parse your response.
   If something is found (there could be `John Doe` and `John Doe 1`, etc), check their email addresses. If match is found, bind its QuickBooks ID to the customer in your e-commerce DB. You will refer to this ID in further requests. Skip step #3.

If nothing is found, add a new customer (step 3).

3. Adding a customer. Use CustomerAdd XML now:

   ```
   $name = 'John Doe';
   $firstname = 'John';
   $lastname = 'Doe';
   $address_xml = ''; // Put address XML block here

   $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
       <QBXML>
           <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
               <CustomerAddRq>
                   <CustomerAdd>
                       <Name>' . $name . '</Name>
                       <CompanyName></CompanyName>
                       <FirstName>' . $firstname . '</FirstName>
                       <LastName>' . $lastname . '</LastName>
                       ' . $address_xml . '
                       <Phone>555-555-55</Phone>
                       <AltPhone></AltPhone>
                       <Fax>555-555-55</Fax>
                       <Email>john@doe.com</Email>
                       <Contact>' . $name . '</Contact>
                   </CustomerAdd>
               </CustomerAddRq>
           </QBXMLMsgsRq>
       </QBXML>';
   ```
4. Parse your request and store QuickBooks ID in your database to refer to it in future.
5. Build your InvoiceAdd XML and specify a customer ID (not Name):

   ```
   $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <?qbxml version="13.0"?>
           <QBXML>
               <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                   <InvoiceAddRq>
                       <InvoiceAdd>
                           <CustomerRef>
                               <ListID>' . $id . '</ListID>
                           </CustomerRef>
                           <!-- rest of XML -->
      ';
   ```
6. Don't forget to save QuickBooks ID of just created invoice in your database.

Comment: Thank you for your time compiling the answer